# How does the call 'new' invoke user-defined placement allocation function?

Tags: c++

The call `int *a = new(__FILE__, __LINE__) int;` can invoke the function `void* operator new(size_t , const char *, unsigned int );`.

How it work?

Comment: Um... It works literally as you stated it. Expression `new(__FILE__, __LINE__) int` will internally attempt to resolve and call `::operator new` function with the corresponding list of parameters.

Comment: [new expression](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every operator in C++ has a specific syntax and semantic requirements, and those must be respected even after overload. E.g. even you overload the caret `^` operator to represent `power`, you can't expect it to have a higher precedence than multiplication `*`, which will be case in Algebra.

The `new` operator has a syntax requirement as following.

```
new (arguments ... /*for specialized case*/) Type (initializer list);
new (arguments ... /*for specialized case*/) Type [size_t];
```

So, to be able to use `void* operator new  ( std::size_t count, void* ptr );` one has to write following code.

```
int main()
{
    char arr[sizeof(int)];
    int *a = new(arr) int;
}
```

While `void* operator new  ( std::size_t count );` can be called without any glitches as.

```
int main()
{
    int *a = new int;
}
```

So, all the arguments except the first one(which it automatically deduces from type) should be placed between `new` and `type` and should be enclosed in `parenthesis`.

So, in your example `int *a = new(__FILE__, __LINE__) int;`, syntax rules of **new**, seeks `operator new(std::size_t count, char const *, int)`