# What does new(3) mean?

Tags: c++, memory-management, operator-overloading, new-operator

```
SelectInst *Sel = new(3) SelectInst(C, S1, S2, NameStr, InsertBefore);
```

What's the meaning of the `new` operator here?

What's the meaning of the number `3` after the `new` operator?

Comment: `SelectInst` may have overload for new int (similar to placement new). See last note of [operator_new](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new).

Comment: @Jarod42 You're right. Thanks a lot, sorry for the easy problem.

Comment: Check this answer too. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40144788/how-does-the-call-new-invoke-user-defined-placement-allocation-function/40148610#40148610

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This code comes from [LLVM's codebase](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm/blob/52b02289490c18db02a1f0d79e8ca404cdf1ffaf/include/llvm/IR/Instructions.h#L1983).
There's a custom `operator new` [in scope](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm/blob/cb58e1e3bce2898afcd189005154089f4211b005/lib/IR/User.cpp#L146) and it is being used to [placement-new](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new) initialize the objects (cfr. [placement syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Placement_syntax#Expressions))

```
void *User::operator new(size_t Size, unsigned Us) {
  return allocateFixedOperandUser(Size, Us, 0);
}
```

Here's a toy example:

```
class SelectInst
{
public:
  int x;
};

void *operator new(size_t Size, unsigned Us) {
                                ^^^^^^^^^^^ 3 is passed here
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^ allocation size requested

  return ... // Allocates enough space for Size and for Us uses
}

SelectInst *Create() {
  return new(3) SelectInst();
}

int main()
{
  auto ptr = Create();
  return 0;
}
```

<kbd>[Live Example](http://ideone.com/LUydWc)</kbd>

Specifically that code is being used to adjust the allocated space to fit additional data.

Answer (score 7):

Suppose `SelectInst` provides a user-defined [placement operator new](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new), which takes an `int` as user-defined argument; the invocation syntax means use that user-defined placement `operator new` for memory allocation. e.g.

```
class SelectInst {
public:
    static void* operator new (std::size_t count, int args) {
    //                                            ~~~~~~~~
        ...
    }
};

SelectInst *Sel = new(3) SelectInst(C, S1, S2, NameStr, InsertBefore);
//                   ~~~
```

Answer (score 4):

You probably have custom operator new in `SelectInst` or at global scope (similarly to *placement new*):

```
struct SelectInst
{
    SelectInst(/*...*/);
    // ...

    static void* operator new(std::size_t sz, int custom);
    static void operator delete(void* ptr, int custom); // new counter part
};
```

or

```
void* operator new(std::size_t sz, int custom);
void operator delete(void* ptr, int custom); // new counter part
```

See last part of [operator_new](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new)

Answer (score -1):

On the [doc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/operator%20new/) , it says that this is the amount of memory to request in bytes. (If it wasn't overloaded)
Here's this is a request of 3 *8 = 24 bit to store the objet in memory. 
Think of this at some sort of remnant of malloc.